# Should anything be done about a misleading question?

Tags: discussion, questions, rejected-edits

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1295068/windows-equiv-of-the-head-command) asks whether or not there is a Windows equivalent of the `head` command.

Unfortunately there are two fairly major issues:

1. The person asking the question provides an example that shows that they actually want the Windows equivalent of the `tail` command.
2. The highest voted and accepted answer shows that the person asking the question really did want the Windows equivalent of the `tail` command.

Having been caught out by the confusion myself, I put a [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3541023) in to correct the question so that instead of "head" it said "tail" - so now the question being asked, the example, the answers and the accepted answer now make sense. However this was rejected 3-1 because it "changed too much in the original post"

I don't really mind if this is seen as the right thing to do. I don't set the rules after all.

However it just seems a little odd that future visitors who Google "windows head command" will get this page as the first result and think that it was they are getting - but actually end up with a Windows version of `tail`? To me, that doesn't feel right.

Comment: [meta-tag:status-completed]

Comment: Thanks :) There is one other place in the question where the person states "I have a file and I want a way to stip off the first n lines of text" when it should say "I have a file and I want a way to stip off the **last** n lines of text"

Comment: The example output snips off the _first_ line, which is also the behavior of `tail`. That sentence is correct as far as I can see.

Comment: Good point, the typo made me misread it! Well, that's my excuse and I'm sticking with it...

Comment: Fair enough. I am chagrined that I missed the typo on the first pass!

Comment: This is a fairly common problem. I usually make edits to questions so they say what the OP means. Since I can't read minds, I make the determination based on the OP's responses to comments, their comments on answers, and any code in the question.

Comment: I just had this same issue.  The question was filled with irrelevant details so I edited it to ask the *actual* question they wanted.  But my edits were rejected because it "deviates from the original intent."  I suspect editors don't read the question, the responses, the answers, and make a determination.  They see a paragraph of text was change and reject immediately.  http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5992949